# Для чего нужны синглетные классы

Tags: ооп

Для чего в проектировании используются синглетные классы (Могут содержать только один экземпляр)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Синглтон (англ. Singleton) - это экземпляр класса, который может быть только один во всей системе. Допустим класс UserService, с помощью которого будет произведен запрос к серверу для авторизации/аутентификации. Нет необходимости создать каждый раз экземпляр класса UserService. Данный класс будет описан как синглтон и в системе будет только один экземпляр (при попытке создать новый экземпляр, будет возвращаться результат первого создания, т.е. первый и единственный экземпляр).

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на Ваш вопрос заключён в его формулировке.

Синглетные классы (или по другому паттерн [Singleton](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))) используются в тех случаях, когда требуется обеспечить единственную "точку доступа" к тем или иным данным или функциям программы.